# Execute multiple batch files one after another using java

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to execute the same batch file one after another in my java application. 
I want to wait until the batch file is done and just then to execute the next. 
I'm using runtime and then waitFor but it's not working.

Please assist me.

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far.

Comment: On windows? Or on linux?

Comment: Or Try making another batch file C that executes A and B consecutively. Then run file C in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try with below code it will fix your problem:-

```
String[] command ={"/pathto/your/batch.sh", "commandLineParameter"};
//for example if you run your batch manually like 'mybatch.sh  today'
// so your command line parameter is today
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectOutput(new File("/tmp/output.txt"));
    //in the above output.txt you can see the output from the command
   while(true){
      try {
             Process p = pb.start();
             p.waitFor();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
           }catch (Exception e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
       }
        if(something)//put your condition here when to break the loop
           break;
   }//end of while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProcessBuilder refer : [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)  or [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/)

Find example of [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html). 
It abstracts you way of a lot of the common problems associated with your approach.